# Do we need to have DOCTYPE Declaration of html5 for data-attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is this really needed when we data-attr for the elements in html

```
<input type ="text" name="text1" id ="text1" data-attr="<?php echo $hell ?>">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it needed? **no**.  Will it pass the W3C validator without it? **no**.

You'll have no actual issues using data attributes either way, it just depends how important validation is to you.

- Without HTML5 DOCTYPE: It'll work, the validator will fail with an HTML4 doctype.
- With HTML5 DOCTYPE: It'll work *and* be valid.

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't **need** to write your code any particular way.

You **should** provide the correct doctype for the content. If you'd like to add data elements/attributes in HTML4 and below, you can namespace your elements and attributes (`mydata:attr="..."`).